# printing a set for dictionary values - python

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm having trouble formatting my output in python 3.0. The values are in a set for each key.

The output I have now is:

```
AAG -> ['AGA']
AGA -> ['GAT']
ATT -> ['TTC']
CTA -> ['TAC']
CTC -> ['TCT']
GAT -> ['ATT']
TCT -> ['CTA', 'CTC']
TTC -> ['TCT']
```

The output I need is:

```
AAG -> AGA
AGA -> GAT
ATT -> TTC
CTA -> TAC
CTC -> TCT
GAT -> ATT
TCT -> CTA,CTC
TTC -> TCT
```

This is what my code currently looks like. Also the dictionary has to be sorted by keys.

```
#sort lexigraphically by keys
for key in sorted(theDict):
    print("%s -> %s" % (key, theDict[key]))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can `join` the values for each key as a string and then format it:

```
for key in sorted(theDict):
    print("%s -> %s" % (key, ','.join(theDict[key])))
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

`theDict[key]` is a list of strings, but you want to join the list into a single string before printing it.  Try `','.join(theDict[key])`.